# Javascript in Adobe not working properly

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have the following code in a column of fields on an Adobe form:

```
var ro = true;
var plan = Number(this.getField("Option1").value);
if (plan==100) 
  event.value = "$0";
else if (plan==125) 
  event.value = "$0";
else if (plan==150) 
  event.value = "$0";
else if (plan==200) 
  event.value = "$0";
else {
  event.value = "";
  ro = false;
}
event.target.readonly = ro;
```

So based on this the field in question is supposed to take a look at the field named "Option1" and if one of four (4) predetermined values are present ($100, $125, $150 or $200) the field should display "$0" and the field is set as read only.

If none of those four (4) predetermined values are present then the field should unlock to allow for manual data entry.

Everything works fine except that when I tab out of the field it deletes any data I've manually entered.

I am perplexed. Can anyone give any guidance here?

Thanks!

**EDIT** - Picture added to show how fields are named on the page.
[Form Fields Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Egq9.jpg)

In the image, the fields in the blue box all check the field labeled "Option1" for it's value. The fields in the green box check "Option2", yellow is "Option3" and black is "Option4".

The overarching purpose here is to create a sales form that will auto-populate plan details based on one of 4 predetermined contribution levels OR allow for manual data entry.

Comment: To which field, and which event did you attach the above listed code? Are there calculations elsewhere in the form?

Comment: There are no other calculations. The script was edited to give specific output for each field. There are a little over 90 fields on the form, 4 columns with 31 fields in each column. Each field at the top is identified by a unique name so the script will only look at the cell at the top of it's respective column. The trigger is entering data into that top field. If it's one of 4 pre-determined values it should output a value and go readonly otherwise it should allow for manual data entry. It does that fine. The problem is that it clears data entered by the user upon moving to another cell.

Comment: OK, that is the answer to the second question. What about the first question?

Comment: The code was added to the "Custom Calculation Script" on the "Calculate" tab for the "Text Field Properties" for all fields in each column except the uppermost one.